# Kafka & JPA transaction management

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I am new to Kafka and trying to do transaction management for Kafka and DB transaction. I already read many articles on this topic, but so far I am able to test only 1 scenario successfully.

```
@Transactional
public void updateData(InputData data)
{
  
  repository.save(data);
  kafkaTemplate.send(data.id,data);
}
```

In this case if Kafka transactions fails, DB transaction will be rollback. This works fine.

But is it possible to do Kafka transaction first & then DB transaction? and if DB transaction fails, then the Kafka transaction will be aborted & message posted on Kafka topic will be in uncommitted state?

I tested such scenario, but it didn't work. Message posted on topic was not in uncommitted state. Hence want to check possibility of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It is solved by using nested @transactional annotation. I put @transactional("kafkaTxManager) on the method in which I am starting kafka transaction & put @transactional("chainkafkaTxmanager") on the method where i am starting DB transaction.

Comment: can you share sample code which shows this??